# Checking empty file returns as non-empty

Tags: bash, shell

When I'm using one of the comparison operators/functions on an empty file, Bash returns that the file is not empty. There must be a newline character or something, but it's making all these tests pass when they shouldn't.

So is there another way to test if a file actually has a character? I've tried `[ -s file.txt ]`, `[ -n file.txt]`, and all its brethren, but they all return that the file.txt is not empty.

I've tried doing `cat` and assigning it to a variable, but that variable is read as not empty for some reason.

Any other way to see if a file is truly empty?

edit
So here's what I've done. I cleared the file (ctrl+a and delete). Made sure when I tried moving cursor that the cursor doesn't move. Then I did `if [ -n filename ] ; then echo "not empty"; fi;` This  returns `not empty`

Comment: Define "truly empty"? Does only spaces count as empty? Does only newlines count as empty? Does spaces and newlines count as empty? What about tabs? What about vertical tabs? What about other control characters? `-s` tells you if the file is *entirely* empty i.e. has no contents. If you need something else you'll need to figure out what you need and how to test for it.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the actual code you tried as well as the actual and expected output? For example, instead of saying "I've tried `[ -s file.txt ]`", can you say "I've tried this: `> file.txt; ls -l file.txt; [ -s file.txt ] && echo "the file is empty"` but it shows `-rw-r------ 1 me me 0 Jun 18 10:32 file.txt` while I expected it to also show "the file is empty" because the file size is 0"?

Comment: What does `ctrl+a` and `delete` mean?  Which editor are you using?  What does it save when you save that empty file?  What does `ls -l` say is the size of the file?  At this point, it sounds like it might be an editor problem, not a shell problem.  Does your editor create empty files?

Comment: `ctrl+a` and `delete` to select everything and delete it. I'm using Notepad++ and `ls -l` shows `0` bytes, Windows also shows 0 bytes. I'm using Cygwin on windows

Comment: Mentioning Windows and Cygwin is helpful, though mostly Cygwin manages to run like Unix.  Note that the `-n` operator is a string test, not a file test.  What happens if you replace `-n` with `-s`?

Comment: well obviously I change the other argument to a string for the appropriate operator, but they both return not empty

Answer (score 1):

The test for a non-empty file is:

```
[ -s file.txt ]
```

The test for an empty file, therefore, is:

```
[ ! -s file.txt ]
```

or you can use Bash's `!` operator outside the test command:

```
if ! [ -s file.txt ]
```

Note that these operations consider a file 'empty' if it contains zero bytes.  If it is bigger than that, it is not empty by definition.  If you want to inspect the contents and ignore a file that contains only blanks and newlines, etc, then you need a different test altogether.

You can consider using the `[[` command (a shell built-in with a number of special semantics) instead of `[`, though in this context, it makes no practical difference.  The `[[` command is not as portable as `[`.

Note that the `-n` option tests for a non-empty string (not a non-empty file).

```
[ -n file.txt ]
```

will always pass (because `file.txt` is not an empty string).  It is used with variables:

```
[ -n "$variable" ]    # Is $variable non-empty
[ -z "$emptyvar" ]    # Is $emptyvar empty
```

Comment: The part about "that variable is read as not empty for some reason." was probably due to using `[ -n $variable ]`, which due to the lack of quoting is true for empty input.

Comment: @thatotherguy: If you have: `variable=""` followed by `[ -n $variable ]` then you have an erroneous invocation of the test built-in (at least, in classic shell -- meaning pre-POSIX 90; Bash seems to handle it, and so does Linux's `/usr/bin/[`).  You could use `[[ -n $variable ]]` because that is special in many ways, whereas `[` is just a regular command (there is usually a binary `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[` that you can use, though it is also a shell built-in).

Comment: No, it's not erronous; `[ string ]` is true when the string is not empty. Therefore, OP's `var=$(cat emptyfile); [ -n $var ]` would have expanded to `[ -n ]` which is true because "-n" is a non-empty string. Had the file contained "foo", it would have expanded to `[ -n foo ]` which is also true, this time because "foo" is non-empty.

Comment: POSIX may have changed things; it's entirely possible.  I didn't bother to learn the sloppy techniques because the rigorous ones work reliably.

Comment: Could you be misremembering this? It was not changed in POSIX: it was this way in the original Bourne shell. This is because `[` was an external utility (like GNU coreutils `/usr/bin/[`), and external utilities can not tell the difference between `[ -n ]` and `[ -n $emptyvar ]` due to argv being identical. You also can't error on `[ -n ]`, because for the same reason you can't tell it apart from valid `[ $1 ]` when the first argument is `-n`.

Comment: Yes, I could be misremembering; it was 25 and more years ago.  But I definitely don't like the versions without the explicit `-n` or `-z`.  Using those options (and double quotes) is easy, explicit, and the test can't be misinterpreted.  You may do as you wish.  I will continue to do what works reliably for me.  I regard this discussion as closed.

Comment: OP wrote, quote, "I've tried doing cat and assigning it to a variable, but that variable is read as not empty for some reason.", and I explained the probable reason why they would believe that to clear up the misunderstanding. I did not suggest or recommend `[ $string ]`, not to OP and not to you.